# Extend umbraco member with property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I am developing web site on umbraco and need to store additional information about member(cmsMember). How can I do that? Is there a way to extend umbraco member without changing membership provider?

I would like to do something similar to this

```
  var datatype = new DataTypeDefinition("varchar");
  var type = new PropertyType(datatype);
  var property = new Property(type);
  property.Value = myAdditionalInfo;
  member.Properties.Add(property);
  memberService.Save(member, false);
```

Code above right now throws exception with `Value cannot be null` message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding properties to a Member type can (and should) be done in the backoffice:

[image: Member Type Properties]

And then setting/saving the values should be something like this (using MemberService), though I'm not exactly sure if it's current :-s :

```
// Get the member
var member = Member.GetCurrentMember();

// Check if there is a current member
if (member != null)
{
    // Update member properties
    member.getProperty("myPropertyAlias").Value = myAdditionalInfo;

    // Save the updated member
    member.Save(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jannik this solves my issue, but one more thing necessary. I have to hide this property so that nobody can see content as I am going to save some sensitive data. Can I do this with approach you proposed?

Comment: Hide from who? Anyone logged into Umbraco, or just from the member him-/herself? If in backoffice, take a look at this (beta) package that might help hiding properties (or maybe just try and see how it's done via the source code): https://our.umbraco.org/projects/collaboration/backoffice-tweaking

Comment: hide it from everyone, make it invisible or unavailable in backoffice, but leave for saving data

Comment: I will mark this as an answer and will create another question. Thank you very much Jannik!

Comment: You're welcome! It sounds a lot like something you could do with that Backoffice Tweaking package, it simply hides stuff (properties) from the backend, but you would still be able to access and update from code :-)

Comment: well this is possible, but I am trying to avoid adding dependencies on packages or changing default behavior of Umbraco

Comment: Fair enough. Just a thought, though. Why not just obfuscate/encrypt the value so it doesn't make sense to editors? Then you could just use a Label property type so editors cannot edit it, but you could still update at your own will.