# Add additional fields in Umbraco membership profile

Tags: umbraco7, membership

I am developing a site using Umbraco 7 where HomePage has a Signup form with several fields.
I have created a partial View using Register Member Template and call the Partial View on my HomePage.
Everything is working fine but i need to add some extra fields in the form(like Last name, Phone no., Address etc).
Is there any way to modify existing Member Profile Model to add these fields?
I am new to Umbraco so any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend umbraco member with property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998177/extend-umbraco-member-with-property)

Comment: I am not asking for adding properties..I want to add additional field along with default Name,Email and Password field in profile.

Comment: Aren't properties and field the same thing?

Comment: there are different tables for both..default fields that are already defined under Profile are saved in **cmsMember** table while additional properties are inserting in **cmsPropertyType**  table. I want to know is there any way to add extra columns in **cmsMember** table and use it in application as well.

Comment: Changing the database is not the way to do things in Umbraco (unless it's introducing new tables for volatile data to enhance documents or add metadata). The additional fields you are speaking of are structural additions for you member and need to be added to your membertype. See below answer on how to implement new properties and show them in your views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add the properties to the membertype.

Mark them as editable:

[image]

Finally output them in your view:

```
for (var i = 0; i < registerModel.MemberProperties.Count; i++)
{
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="@Html.IdFor(m => registerModel.MemberProperties[i].Value)">
           @registerModel.MemberProperties[i].Name
           @Html.HiddenFor(m => registerModel.MemberProperties[i].Alias)
       </label>
       @Html.EditorFor(m => registerModel.MemberProperties[i].Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
   </div>
}
```

Note: registerModel is of type Umbraco.Web.Models.RegisterModel

Also check out [UmbracoIdentity](https://github.com/Shazwazza/UmbracoIdentity), a great open source package that shows how to handle member related functionality

Comment: And how is this not a duplicate question/answer as I suggested? :-s

Comment: @JannikAnker This is not duplicate because the question is not only about adding a new property to a member, but how to add an editable property that the member can edit through the front-end of the website